# I am trying to find the cells that contain specific text using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have a column of data that contains different data sets in which i am trying to find the data sets that contain "SBP".

I tried to use an If statement and wildcards but unfamiliar with the way this would work in VBA.

An example of a cell containing what I am looking for would be 
"LM12341234 - SBP - Updates to Main"

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Wa As Worksheet

Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

With Wa
    LastRow = Worksheets("Analysis").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

    If Range(i + 1, "D").Value = "*SBP*" Then

    Range(i + 1, "A").Value = "Project"

    End If

    Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Add the Code that you have tried.

Comment: Mikku, I added what I tried.

Comment: you could also try `arrays` which is faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

- Range Reference Corrected
- Use of `Instr` to match the result
- With Statement was not correctly used

**Here:**

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Wa As Worksheet

Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

With Wa

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If InStr(1, .Range("D" & i + 1).Value, "SBP") > 0 Then

        .Range("A" & i + 1).Value = "Project"

        End If

    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Mikku what does the 1 represent in the if statement after the InStr? I understand the rest. Thanks

Comment: To start looking from 1st character in the Cell. Did the code work ?

Comment: Yes  it did. Thanks again Mikku